# Kivymd не правильно отображает MDTextField

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Я пишу программу для работы на `kivymd`, и столкнулся с такой проблемой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поле для ввода отображается неправильно - причём, любая его форма `kivymd`.
А поле ввода `kivy` работает как надо.
Подскажите, с чем это может быть связано.

Мой код в файле `.kv`:

```
MDTextField:
    id: input
    font_size: dp(20)
    hint_text:'Введите запрос: '
    multiline: False
    size_hint: (.8, .05)
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .58, "center_y": .90}
    on_text_validate: root.process()
```

Вот код полностью:

```
<WindowManager>:
    name: "spare"
    #font_size: dp(20)
    #font_name: 'font/20976.ttf'
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            source: ".venv/images/background-spare.png"
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    DataWindow:
        id: data_scr

    MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
        size_hint: None, None
        size_hint: 0.147,0.1
        pos: 5, 485
        line_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
        text: '[color=#95C2CB]От запчасти[/color]'
        icon: "cellphone-cog"
        icon_color: "white"
        color: 0.94,1,1,0.95

    MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
        size_hint: None, None
        size_hint: 0.147,0.1
        pos: 5, 425
        line_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
        text: '[color=#95C2CB]От стоимости[/color]'
        #icon: "logo",
        #color: 0.94,1,1,0.95
        #background_color: 0.23,0.31,0.31,1
        #border: (1, 1, 1, 1)

    MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
        size_hint: None, None
        size_hint: 0.147,0.1
        pos: 5, 365
        line_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
        text: '[color=#95C2CB]Таблица (Iphone)[/color]'
        icon: "apple"
        icon_color: "white"

    MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
        size_hint: None, None
        size_hint: 0.147,0.1
        pos: 5, 305
        line_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
        text: '[color=#95C2CB]График[/color]'
        icon: "calendar-month"
        icon_color: "white"
        #background_color: 0.23,0.31,0.31,1
        #border: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "graf"

    MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
        size_hint: None, None
        size_hint: 0.147,0.1
        pos: 5, 5
        line_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.03
        text: '[color=#95C2CB]Выход[/color]'
        #icon: "logo",
        #color: 0.94,1,1,0.95
        #background_color: 0.23,0.31,0.31,1
        #border: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "Back-gr"


    MDTextField:
        id: input
        font_size: dp(20)
        #mode: "rectangle"
        #line_color_normal: "white"
        hint_text:'Введите запрос: '
        multiline: False
        size_hint: (.8, .05)
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .58, "center_y": .90}
        on_text_validate: root.process()

    Label:
        font_size: dp(25)
        color: 0,0,0.1,0.6
        pos_hint: {"x":-0.20, "top":0.603}
        text: 'Стоимость ремонта: '

    Label:
        id: res_text
        font_size: dp(27)
        color: 0,0,0.1,0.9
        pos_hint: {"x":-0.035, "top":0.603}
        text: ''
```

Answer (score 0):

В итоге я разобрался, в чем было дело. Проблема была из-за метода build в main.py
Я назвал свой .kv файл так же, как функцию Main, поэтому kivy подгружал его сам, а в моем методе build я возвращаю .kv
Не надо вызывать то, что подгружается само, поэтому некоторые элементы работали не так, как хотелось.